# Update frame of UIView with label in it after changing label's contents

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a custom view which contains a label in it (assume the label is pinned to all the edges of the view). The width of the custom view depends on the text property (naturally, the longer the text the longer the view is going to be).

However, an issue arises. When I instantiate `let customView = CustomView()` and then assign a new text to the label like `customView.textLabel.text "New text"`, the frame of the custom view is still zero. I think this is because I didn't set a frame at the beginning.

If I decide to set an initial frame at init time (`let customView = CustomView(CGFrame(...))`) and then update the label content, the frame does not change its `width`. Why? How can I have a dynamic view that adapts its frame to its content? Calling `sizeToFit` on the label or view does not change the frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I have a dynamic view that adapts its frame to its content?

The usual thing is to position the view with auto layout and override `intrinsicContentSize` to supply the width and height based on the content views (such as the label). The auto layout engine will obey the `intrinsicContentSize` automatically.

Note that the intrinsic content size doesn't magically know its own dependencies; it's up to you call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` whenever you change a dependency (such as the text of the label), so that `intrinsicContentSize` is called again to recalculate the height and width.

In this example, CustomView is the red view, and the label inside it with a white background is its `textLabel`. Note how the red view automatically expands and contracts in synchrony with the automatic expansion and contraction of the label as the label's text changes.

[image]

This is a very simple example for purposes of illustration, so my implementation of CustomView is very simple:

```
class CustomView : UIView {
    @IBOutlet var textLabel : UILabel!
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let w = self.textLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width + 40
        let h = self.textLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height + 40
        return CGSize(width: w, height: h)
    }
}
```

And now the buttons just say this sort of thing:

```
    self.customView.textLabel.text = // whatever
    self.customView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let customView = CustomView(frame:CGRect.zero)
customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(customView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ 
    customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor,constant: 50),
    customView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor,constant: 20)
])

customView.lbl.text = "fjdfjdfkjkdfjkdfjjfkdjfkdjkdfjkdfjkdfjfkdjdfkjdfkjkffkj"
```

---

```
class CustomView: UIView {
  var lbl:UILabel!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        createSubviews()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        createSubviews()
    }
    func createSubviews() {
     // craete the label and pin it to all anchors with .lines = 0
      lbl = UILabel()
      lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      lbl.lines = 0
      self.addSubview(lbl)
      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ 
        lbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
        lbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
        lbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
        lbl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
      ])

    }
}
```

Note: the label to wrap , it / it's parent must have a width

Comment: I think you need to add the customView to the parent view if you want to activate those constraints otherwise it might crash

Comment: @Cesare it's a demo

Comment: I don't want to anchor my custom view to anything. I just want to get its dimensions after the label contents have been updated so I can do some stuff with its aspect ratio.

Comment: @Cesare try what in answer

Answer (score 0):

First we need to take a look at your code of your custom class
but as far as i can remember youl need to set constrains to determinate the size of your view. The easiest way is to create an cutom view with xcode.
[tutorial here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW3)
but i assume that your already familar with this. So sometimes you need to tell swifts uikit to regenerate / refresh the constrains.

Comment: Which constraints should I set? I want my view to have a dynamic width, so whatever width I may set may change in the future

Comment: To get yo right the lable should set the width for the parent. And change the width as you change the text. you can set this in swift but i wont recommend this as this is like poking your own eye. In the designer select your container in the left sidebar - list and crtl drag the line to your lable find an property like width and set it to equal

Comment: Correct me if im wrong else ill update my answer to include this